# Understanding a method from objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I need some help understanding this line of code:

```
- (void)addStockHoldingObject:(StockHolding *)a
{
    if (!stockHolding) {
        stockHolding = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [stockHolding addObject:a];
}
```

Particularly why the "*" pointer declaration is not followed by a variable and why "a" is outside the argument.

Also, what does (!stockHolding) mean?

Comment: first tell me what is stockHolding in if(!stockHolding) , from where you got that object .

Comment: (!stockHolding) means , you are checking whether memory is allocated to stockHolding on not i.e object created or not . if object not yet created then it will return nil . so if object is not created then your allocating memory to it .

Comment: (StockHolding *) is representing an type .so '*' is inside .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this method `a` is the parameter of class `StockHolding.` So when passing parameter to the method, always * symbol followed by class. So that it will typecast to the object accordingly. For example below:-

This is the `NSString` class method:-

```
+ (id)stringWithString:(NSString *)aString
```

In this aString is the parameter whose type refers to `NSString` class. so if we call this method we can directly pass the string object without typecasting for example below:-

```
NSString *str=[NSString stringWithString:@"yourString"];
```

The advantage is that without doing type casting we can pass string to the parameter of the method.
Also `if (!stockHolding)` is just checking nil it means, if object is no longer exist then just allocating the same.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are from C(++). You need to read how methods are declared in Objective-C. In brief the syntax for an argument declaration contains:

```
( <type> ) <identifier>
```

and in your example the type is `StockHolding *` and the identifier `a`.

The expression `!stockholding` is just the standard C-ism for `stockholding == nil` - the latter being more explicit so the former is preferred by C aficionados ;-)

I suggest you go read one of the introductions to the Objective-C language.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more implementation code it appears to mean 
If the stockholding mutable array ivar is nil then allocate and initialize it. This is a common guard. 
Once you are sure the array is non nil, add the passed in Stockholding object to the array.

```
- (void)addStockHoldingObject:(StockHolding *)a
{
    if (!stockHolding) {
        stockHolding = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [stockHolding addObject:a];
}
```